# VBA | Adding Partial Rows Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of wells and several lists of well production data. I am trying to setup the data so that it is representative of the relative time to the year.

For example:
[image]
I have Well A starting on day 1, but well B starts on day 6. I am trying to figure out a Macro that will auto space the production for me based on a delay scalar: X1 = 5 Days.

Is there a way to achieve this with a VBA code?

```
 Sub InsertAttempt()
    '
        Range("F3:H7").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("I3:K12").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("L3:N17").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End Sub​
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "...auto space the production for me"?  Does your code do what you want, does it error, ...what's it doing?

Comment: @BruceWayne My apologies. I have about 1,000 wells to load into the excel file. I have a separate tab with all of the production data and want this VBA formula to automatically. I would like for the production to space itself on the new page with the true dates, since the production dates are all different. The code I have written does what I want, but I want it to occur automatically so I don't need to copy and past each well.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Do I understand correctly - your code provided works, and does what you want.  However, there's also columns `O:Q`, then `R:T`, then `U:W`, etc. you want to do this on, but don't want to just have the same code written dozens of times? It looks like you're doing this in three column "chunks", yeah?

Comment: @BryceWayne - yes exactly like that! I also want to be able to change the Delay between the wells by a scalar. In this example I used 5, but 7 days is also pretty standard.

Comment: Since I have to put down the oil, gas, and water production, I have to separate allocate each well with a column, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure if this works, now that I look at it, but try it out and let me know where/if it goes wrong:

```
Sub InsertAttempt()
Dim lastColCell As Range
Set lastColCell = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

Dim i As Long, k As Long
k = 0
For i = 6 To lastColCell.Column
    Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(7 + k, i + 2)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    k = k + 5
    i = i + 2
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works exactly how I wanted it to - apologies for the lack of clarity in my original question.

Comment: @LandonWright if it works, do you mind marking it as the answer? (Click the check mark left of the post, by the up/down arrows)

Comment: I did that. Thanks for your help!